# How to attach environments by a loop?

Tags: r, variables, search, environment

I'm trying to attach several environments by a loop.

```
env.a <- new.env()
env.b <- new.env()
env.c <- new.env()

attach(env.a)
search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "env.a"             "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[10] "package:base"    
detach(env.a)

# Now do it in a loop
for (e in c("env.a", "env.b", "env.c")) {
+ if (!e %in% search()) { attach(get(e)) }
+ }
search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "get(e)"            "get(e)"           
 [4] "get(e)"            "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
 [7] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[10] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

As shown in the above example, it works if only one variable is attached. When I use a loop to attach them one by one, they will be all named `get(e)` in the search path. However, if I don't use `get(e)`, it will result in an error.

```r
for (e in c("env.a", "env.b", "env.c")) {
+ if (!e %in% search()) { attach(e) }
+ }
Error in attach(e) : file 'env.a' not found
```

Does anybody know the right way to do this? 
Thanks,

Comment: Does `attach(get(e), name = e)` work?

Comment: You'd better ban `attach` from your R vocabulary, it'll only get you in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PoGibas's comment, to attach by a loop

```
> for (e in c("env.a", "env.b", "env.c")) {
+ if (!e %in% search()) { attach(get(e), name = e) }
+ }
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "env.c"             "env.b"            
 [4] "env.a"             "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
 [7] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[10] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Conversely, to detach by a loop

```
> for (e in c("env.a", "env.b", "env.c")) {
+ if (e %in% search()) { 
+ detach(e, character.only = TRUE) }
+ }
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```